# SQL ORDER BY Not Working as Intended

Tags: mysql, sql

My `statement` is

```
Select * From Table ORDER By MyDay;
```

I believe my `old statement` was

```
Select * From Table ORDER By MyDay, MyTime
```

and 
I modified it to the `statement` that is above. I have noticed that unless I remove my information and insert again orders it correctly.  `MyDay` is `varchar` and this is the results I get right now.
Is their a way where I can fix this where I can fix this without inserting all the data again

```
Monday
Tuesday
Sunday
Sunday
Monday
Monday
Monday
Tuesday
```

Comment: share the table schema please

Comment: Can you add some sample data, table structure and the expected result?

Comment: If `MyDay` is a `VARCHAR` as you told, the result won't look like this. Try making a SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I have created demo in Fiddle & for me it is working as expected.
It is giving me proper output.

Please Check Here is the Link For Demo

**[Click To See DeMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3493f)**

**Issue**

**1.** I am not sure what may be the issue but
One of the possibility is that you have inserted the SPACE before your days that should be the case

So try **Trim()** function

I have created demo for that also Please Check the Same link

I hope This helps you

Comment: I understand what you are saying but create a table with column a and b insert information.  Add information then order by the column a and b, then insert information the just order by column a and I believe thats was causing my problem